# Change the text within a div that has a class using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble editing text that is within a template using jquery, I can't seem to select it. Here is what I have:

```
<div id="container">
<a class="teamLink smallButton" href="#">Click Here</a>
</div>

<script>
$('.smallButton a').text('new text');
</script>
```

I would like to edit the text "Click Here"

Answer (score 4):

Your selector looks for `a` elements which are descendants of elements with the class `.smallButton`.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.smallButton').text('new text');
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9ntH6/

Comment: @user2547566 I posted a working fiddle. Your issue must be elsewhere, can you post a fiddle that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @user2547566 See my edited answer. You need to wait until the DOM is ready, otherwise the elements you're trying to target don't exist when trying to target them.

Answer (score 0):

Jasons solution should work.
else use only class selector and change the html

$('.smallButton').html('new text');

Comment: Ah thanks, just had to set a timeout function on it, it worked!